# strange behaviour in visual c

Tags: visual-c++

this program hangs after taking first argument:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void ellip(char*,...);
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    printf("a");
    ellip("first argument",99,"second arg","thirdarg");
    _getch();
return 0;
}
void ellip(char* m,...)
{   char com='c';
    for(;;)
        {   
            auto g=0;
            while(com=='c')
            {

                printf("%d\nMatched Continue:-",g++);
                scanf("%c",&com);


            }
        }
}
```

while the same program with a subtle modification(Addition of space)

```
scanf("%c ",&com);
```

Works Fine!

Is this some sort of bug in vc or a problem in my computer?

Comment: Not the solution to your problem, but why do you use `auto g=0;`? It takes 1 character less to type `int g=0;`.

Comment: In my 3 yr. programming era,i was first time just testing auto.

Comment: @programming-tornado: `auto` in C declares an object with automatic storage duration. In ansi c, objects have automatic storage duration by default. Don't confuse this with `auto` in C++0x.

Comment: Please just avoid using `scanf`. http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: conio.h is not C89 or C99 Standard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the new line is read from `stdin` and placed into `com`, then `com` is now `'\n'` and the `for(;;)` loop will loop forever while the `while(com=='c')` will never be entered.

`scanf("%c ",&com);` fixes the problem because the space character will cause `scanf` to  skip over all white space.

See the MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwwtf9ch%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). FIrst bullet point explains what the space charcter is doing.